# Jasmine test for javascript getter not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I'm writing some test for for an angularjs factory and some of the expectations are not working and I really don't know why.

This is my factory (part of it).
'use strict';

```
angular.module('myAppMod')
  .factory('Person', function(BaseModel) {
    return BaseModel.extend({
      get fullname() {
        var name = [];
        if (this.first_name) {
          name.push(this.first_name);
        }
        if (this.person_extra && this.person_extra.middle_name) {
          name.push(this.person_extra.middle_name);
        }
        if (this.last_name) {
          name.push(this.last_name);
        }
        return name.join(' ');
      }
    });
  });
```

and Jasmine tests:

```
var p;
beforeEach(function() {
  p = new Person({
    first_name: 'first_name',
    person_extra: {
      middle_name: 'middle_name',
      media_item_id: null
    },
    last_name: 'last_name',
    security_level: 'security_level'
  }, true);
});

it("has a fullname", function() {
  expect(p.fullname).toEqual('first_name middle_name last_name');
});
```

`p.fullname`is returning `""`(empty string) and in the factory, `console.log(this.first_name)`, is `undefined`.

Any help is really appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you show the complete code of the factory? Thanks.

Comment: Which dialect of Javascript are you writing this in? And which browser are you running the test in? Do you know for certain that the get syntax is supported by the browser running the test? For example, maybe PhantomJS doesn't support getters ... just thinking out loud.

Comment: @SunilD. is plain javascript. I'm using Chrome latest on a mac.

Comment: @alecxe just updated the factory

Comment: What is `BaseModel`? Plain JS objects don't have an `extend()` method. Is it a Backbone model?

Comment: BaseModel is a JS class. It has an extend method to extend what ever I want

Comment: I have updated my answer and found the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: After further investigation, I have changed my answer.

It is not working because you are using the *getter* shorthand (`get fnName() { }`) through the `extend` method. The *getter's* `this` is the anonymous object itself and **does not inherit the methods and properties of the Backbone model**, whereas the `this` in function properties do. I have made a [codepen that illustrate your problem](http://codepen.io/charlespwd/pen/EPPpPG?editors=101).

That is, if this is your Model

```
 var Model = BaseModel.extend({
   get isBackboneModelThroughGetter() {
     return !!this.get;
   },
   isBackboneModel: function() {
     return !!this.get;
   },
 });
```

Then an instance of Model will make this test pass:

```
it('should make you wonder', function() {
   var model = new Model();
   expect(model.isBackboneModel()).toBe(true);
   expect(model.isBackboneModelThroughGetter).not.toBe(true);
});
```

Thus, to make your Person factory work, you will need:

1. To replace every property access by the proper Backbone call: `this.get('propertyName')` instead of `this.propertyName`
2. Replace all *getters* by function properties: `full_name : function() { /*...*/ }` instead of `get full_name() { /* ... */ }`
3. Replace calls to `model.full_name` by `model.full_name()`;

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're using the built-in `angular.extend`. `angular.extend` does *not* copy getters and setters. There's been [an open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8573) on GitHub on this specific subject since the 12th of August 2014.

As for why it still isn't implemented:

> Angular exposes some of the helper functions that it uses internally.  This is the case for `extend`, `copy` and many others. There are other libraries that specialize in these functions, keep their
>   focus is there and can do a better job.
>
> It is not in the best interest of most users to make these helper functions big nor slow, as these are used internally and any change in that direction can have a direct impact in download size and performance. At the same time, apps that need the most accurate version, should be better served with other libraries.

There are many ways to solve this issue. [`decaf.js`](https://github.com/decafjs/decaf/blob/master/builtins/decaf.js#L17) provides an example implementation that should work for most cases. GitHub is probably a better environment to dive into their code, but it comes down to this:

```
function extend (me) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    decaf.each(args, function (o) {
        for (var key in o) {
            if (o.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, key);
                var g = desc.get;
                var s = desc.set;

                if (g || s) {
                    Object.defineProperty(me, key, { get: g, set: s, enumerable: true });
                } else {
                    me[key] = o[key];
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return me;
}
```